# TFS2018 path to api

Tags: tfs

I have a TFS2018 setup on a server and I am trying to figure out what is the path to the api. Should the path look look like this? Do I have to enable the API on the server?

```
https://myserver/tfs/DefaultCollection/MyProject/_apis
```

If I run this in code like this

```
var cred = new VssCredentials(
                        new WindowsCredential(new NetworkCredential("username", "Pass")));
var buildClient = new BuildHttpClient(new Uri("https://myserver/tfs/DefaultCollection/MyProject/_apis", UriKind.Absolute), cred);                       
await buildClient.CreateDefinitionAsync(buildDef);
```

I get the following error

> Web method running:
>   [https://myserver/tfs/DefaultCollection/MyProject/_apis]
>   (OPTIONS)_apis[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how the server was setup. If it's a fresh install, the `/tfs/` is no longer used. If it's an upgrade the `/tfs/` is retained to not break existing clients. And I suspect you can leave off the `/_api/` part as well, as that should be automatically added.

The best way to get to the BuildCLient is to use the TFS Server or Collection object and request the server:

```
var collection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(tfsCollectionUri, credential);
var buildClient = collection.GetClient<BuildHttpClient>();
```

Comment: Ok, so I removed the tfs from the path since this is a fresh install. I still get the same error in code. But if I put the path into the browser I get a page not found The page you are looking for is currently unavailable. I also noticed that tfs is actually part of the path when I navigate on the tfs web. And I removed the _apis from the path.

Comment: If the browser has `/tfs` in the url, you should use it here too. Have you tried the `GetClient`? That should automatically configure the right build api endpoint.

Comment: Thanks this worked. But I have another problem now. When I call var s = await buildClient.CreateDefinitionAsync(buildDef, "MyProject"); I get the response Web method running: [https://myserver/tfs/DefaultCollection/myproject/_apis/build/Definitions] (POST)Definitions[build] and the program quits without going to the next breakpoint. There is no definition created under the project.

Comment: @doorman hard to say what's breaking here. I suspect it's throwing some error. Check Fiddler?